# How to sign in user when testing controllers with rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I have following code

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
post :create, company: attributes_for(:company)
expect Company.count.should == 1
```

I can't execute post because i have authenticate user method on all controllers, how can i sign in user before that action , i am using devise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following into spec/rails_helper.rb:

```
require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

and using `sign_in` method before test like `sign_in @user`

Answer (score 3):

You can stub current_user. Having created @user, you could do this:

```
before(:each) do
  allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).
    to receive(:current_user).and_return(@user)
end
```

Hope this works?